# Parallel functions composition in Functional Programming

Tags: functional-programming, theory

This question is a sub-problem of a bigger problem and this is the last hard nut:

I have two functions:

```py
getUserFromDB :: Token -> Either String User
getNewUser :: Token -> Either String User
```

How do I combine them to get a function like this:

```py
getUser :: Token -> Either String User
```

so that `getUserFromDB` and `getNewUser` are tried in sequence one after another, are fed the same input (`Token` is an api token for OAuth api) and the result of the first succeeded function is returned, or some default value if none succeed?

In other words: if there is a function in FP with signature like:

```py
tryUntilGoodOrFail :: failValue -> (result -> Boolean) -> [fn] -> input -> result
OR
tryUntilGoodOrFail :: a -> (a -> Boolean) -> [(b -> a)] -> b -> a
```

**EDIT**

This is just a newbie question about functional programming in general. I just don't know how to put two (or more) functions in parallel sequence, in contrast to consecutive functions pipe (which FP is very good at). But in realworld cases this parallel sequence functions pattern is what often needed. I believe FP has it's own solution to this. I just can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Why is this tagged "theory"? This sounds very much like a specific Haskell question.

Comment: It's language-agnostic and about FP in general.

Comment: I use Scala, but it sounds like this can be easily done using pattern matching. The final error type in Scala would be written as the superclass of the two error types. I am not sure how to write it in Haskell.

Comment: @Bergi How would you express it in Haskell?

Comment: What is `OneOfTwoFails`? Should it represent both errors from both attempts? Should it just be a generic message signalling failure without any information as to the cause?

Comment: @user2407038 I edited the question to avoid confusion. It may be any value that indicates that none of the functions succeeded.

Comment: @StasShepelev In Haskell, `Either` is an instance of [`Semigroup`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Semigroup.html#t:Semigroup), and has a [default value function](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Either.html#v:fromRight), so you'd just write `fromRight failValue $ getUserFromDB token <> getNewUser token`

Comment: @StasShepelev For a more generic version, you could also do `let (Right result) = sconcat $ map ($ token) [getUserFromDB, getNewUser] |: Right failvalue`

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem is `Eithers` are right-biased, meaning they are designed to short-circuit on the first `Left`, but you want it to short-circuit on the first `Right`.  If you made everything an `Either User String`, then your `getUser` would be:

```
getUser token = getUserFromDb token >> getNewUser token
```

If you want to keep it as `Either String User`, you have to swap it then bind, or do the short-circuiting yourself using an `if` expression or something.

Comment: Wow! This is the first meaningful and educational answer I've got to this problem! Thank you! Do you know if that pattern is rather unpopular in FP? I can't find any "textbook" solutions to this. Switching Left and Right in Either or creating some special container for this use case seems to be overboard.

Comment: By the way `getUserFromDb token` gets the function called (executed) and if I get it right - you can't `>>` them after that. Or can you? In FP value is function that needs not arguments! Right?

Comment: Does `getUserFromDb token` and `getNewUser token` in `getUserFromDb token >> getNewUser token` mean that both functions get executed? I need `getNewUser` to be executed only if `getUserFromDb` fails.

Comment: Haskell is lazy by default. The second function won't be executed unless it needs to.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of sounds like [Applicative Functors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Applicative_functor) (also [here](http://learnyouahaskell.com/functors-applicative-functors-and-monoids)).  Assuming `getNewUser` will return a `Left` (or `Failure` depending on the language) if the user is already in the system then you can use a list of functions and just apply them in sequence and get a list of `Result` back.  Then you can find the first successful result without caring whether it is a new user or an existing one.

This doesn't short-circuit but it does the next best thing.

Comment: Does the list of `Result` mean that all the functions in the input list will be executed? That would mean that all functions can succeed and new user will be created in DB even if `getUserFromDB` will find the searched user and we actually don't need a new one. I assume that would not happen if the language is lazy, like Haskell, but won't suit for non-lazy languages.

Comment: Yes.  That is the nature of applicatives.  That is why I said that `getNewUser` should return a `Left` if the user already exists.  Alternatively, you could just use a normal `bind` and return `Left<Pair<Token, User>>` from each function when a user is found/created and `Right<Token>` when no user is found/created.  This should short-circuit the chain on the first `Left` allowing the `Token` to be passed to the next stage for it to try.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I have found (working for any language lazy or not): `fold` (`foldl` to be more accurate). Don't know how to express it in Haskell or PureScript. Here is my version in Python:

```py
getUser = lambda token: fold(
  lambda e,f:e if e.isRight else f(token),
  left('None Worked'),
  [getUserFromDB, getNewUser, someOtherAttempt, ... ]
)
```

Same for JS:

```js
const getUser = token => fold(
  (e,f)=>e.isRight?e:f(token),
  left('None Worked'),
  [getUserFromDB, getNewUser, someOtherAttempt, ... ]
)
```

PureScript has interesting function called `until` that also can help with it. But it returns a list of results until the first successful one (which is what I was looking for), and I can feed it to `last` and `maybe` and get a first good result or a default value. But `fold` makes it all in one go and is more general and universal and standard.